How can I copy and paste file creation date of multiple workbooks to the last row without data?
Newbie here. I am trying to copy some data from multiple workbooks an paste onto a one workbook. Columns A-Y paste just fine, however I am having issues with column Z (file creation date). Instead of the file creation date of each uploaded file pasting after last row, it's overwriting it. e.g. I have 200 rows of data from file 1 created on 01/01/24, I then go to upload data from file 2 which was created on 02/01/24, the file created column gets overwritten with 02/01/24. I hope this makes sense. Here is the macro I'm using.
This is the code I have tried. I expected the data to upload from file 1 with file creation date being pasted to column Z to all rows with data. When uploading file 2, the file creation date should then be pasted to the last rows without data.
Sub GetFile()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim DataWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim FileCreationDate As Date
    Dim ToLastRow As Long
 
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set DataWorksheet = Sheet1
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
                    .AllowMultiSelect = False
                    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\xxx"
    End With
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")
    
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
    
        Set OpenWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        
        With OpenWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:Y" & LastRow).Copy
        End With
        
    End If
      
        
        If DataWorksheet.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set DestCell = DataWorksheet.Range("A2")
        Else
        Set DestCell = DataWorksheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        
    End If
    
     DestCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
        
        For ToLastRow = 2 To LastRow
        
        FileCreationDate = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(FileToOpen).DateCreated
   
    End If
    
        DataWorksheet.Cells(ToLastRow, 26).Value = FileCreationDate
    
        Next ToLastRow
  
        OpenWorkbook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        OpenWorkbook.Close False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Since you already pasted the data into the sheet, need to calculate new row numbers.
On the other hand there are some problems with the End If statements too.
Pls. try this mod
Sub GetFile()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim DataWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim FileCreationDate As Date
    Dim ToLastRow As Long
    Dim NewLastRow as Long

    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set DataWorksheet = Sheet1
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
                    .AllowMultiSelect = False
                    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\xxx"
    End With
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx*),*xlsx*")
    
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
    
        Set OpenWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        
        With OpenWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:Y" & LastRow).Copy
        End With
        
      
        
        If DataWorksheet.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set DestCell = DataWorksheet.Range("A2")
        Else
        Set DestCell = DataWorksheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        
        End If
    
        DestCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
        NewLastRow = DestCell.End(xlDown).Row
     
        FileCreationDate = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(FileToOpen).DateCreated
        
        For ToLastRow = DestCell.Row To NewLastRow
   
        DataWorksheet.Cells(ToLastRow, 26).Value = FileCreationDate
    
        Next ToLastRow
  
        OpenWorkbook.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        OpenWorkbook.Close False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub

